# How to close the previous dialog after click the signup button in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the bootstrap package to display a login dialog when user click a button, and if user don't have account, he can click the sign up button, and it will direct to a new dialog with sign up form, and the previous login dialog should be closed at the same time. My code is as follow:

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</button>
      <div className="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
        <FacebookButton/>
        <LoginForm/>
        Need an account?    <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" data-dismiss="myModal">Sign up</button>
            <div className="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
            <div className="modal-dialog">
              <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">

              <RegisterForm/>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How should I change my code to achieve this?

Comment: See answer, I just use data-dismiss="modal"

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss No, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the # symbol in front of myModal in data-dismiss in the second button.

If that doesn't work try data-dismiss="modal"

Comment: Make sure the modal fade divs are seperate from each other, not in the same div

Comment: <div class="modal fade"> ... </div> Both should be seperate from each other.

Comment: Von Heiss, no still same